# My js will not work -- Unexpected '<'

Tags: javascript

Why will this not work in JSLint?  Whats wrong with my JS?

```html
<script type="application/javascript"> 
    function feedpixel(){

    var feedpixelpixel = new Image(1,1);feedpixel.src = "http://test.com/pixel/;    
           };
    feedpixel();
</script>
```

```
Unexpected '<'.

<script type="application/javascript"> 

line 1 character 2
Stopping. (14% scanned).
```

Comment: unless its a typo, your `.src =` doesn't have ending quotes.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a quote...
`"http://test.com/pixel/;` should be `"http://test.com/pixel/";`

Comment: You also name the variable `feedpixelpixel` but then only reference it as `feedpixel` when attempting to set the `src`.

Comment: Also you can't feed the `<script>` tags into JSLint.

Comment: @Pointy that's probably the cause of the error

Comment: "application/javascript"? "text/javascript"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed incorrect ending quotations and incorrect reference to variable name.

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function feedpixel(){

            var feedpixelpixel = new Image(1,1);
            feedpixelpixel.src = 'http://test.com/pixel/';    
       };

       feedpixel();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

A few errors:

1. You can't put the `script` tags into JSLint: they're HTML, not JavaScript.
2. It should be `<script type="text/javascript">...</script>` rather than `application/javascript`.
3. You're modifying the `.src` of `feedpixel` (your function) rather than `feedpixelpixel` (your variable): this is where good naming conventions come into play.
4. You're missing a closing parenthesis on the `feedpixelpixel.src` line. It should be

   ```
   var feedpixelpixel = new Image(1,1);
   feedpixelpixel.src = "http://test.com/pixel/";
   ```

   rather than

   ```
   var feedpixelpixel = new Image(1,1);
   feedpixel.src = "http://test.com/pixel/;
   ```

   (Notice the syntax coloring difference on the semicolon.)

*This* is what you should be putting into JSLint:

```
function feedpixel(){
    var feedpixelpixel = new Image(1,1);
    feedpixelpixel.src = "http://test.com/pixel/;"
}

feedpixel();
```